# SecurityError: Load an image in canvas, modify it and create dataURL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm attempting to use HTML5  to bring in an image file, draw it to the canvas, do some manipulation of it, then return the dataURL so that I can reference this newly generated image.

Here's a quick example of what the image loading code looks like:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    cxt = c.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.src = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
    //img.src = 'image/placemark.png';
    img.onload = function() {
        cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }

    console.log(c.toDataURL());
</script>
```

So, with the code like that the log of c.toDataURL() is a blank canvas, presumably because the `log()` call is executed before the `draw()` function finishes. If instead, I move that log call inside `draw()` I get a JavaScript error: `SecurityError: The operation is insecure`

If instead, I use the local image and put the `log` in to the `draw` function, I get the expected output there - but still blank canvas outside the function

I guess my actual question is: how can load in an external image to a canvas, and then modify it's contents in some fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross origin needs to be set on the server hosting the image making it a [CORS enabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CORS_Enabled_Image) if you want to do any sort of image modification.

If this is not set on the server side the only other option is to download the image via a server side proxy on the same domain as your script. As long as the image is coming from the same domain you'll be able to modify it.

Comment: Yeah...that's what I was afraid of. I guess what I'm going to have to do is have an AJAX method go to my server to have PHP go download the file for me.

Comment: @lightstrike If you could accept this answer it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Loktar: Actaully it does not work, the data is not complete in your example:

Infact it introduces the exact error that OP is referring to:

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/squadjot/k5LqB/25/

Answer (score -1):

My code does not have the security error:

```
<pre>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function WindowsLoad()
    {
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var cxt = c.getContext("2d");

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
        //img.src = 'image/placemark.png';
        img.onload = function () {
            cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }

        console.log(c.toDataURL());
    }   
</script>

<body onload="WindowsLoad();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <canvas id="myCanvas">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```