# How to modify an image with canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

In my html I have an image already loaded:

```
<img usemap="#prototypeMap" src="../../projects/tcas/TCAS display.jpg" style="z-index: 2;">
```

Is it possibile create a canvas to modify that image, by javascript?
For example drawing a line in it, changing colours in it (for some pixels) and so on...

EDIT:

I have found a method on Internet but it doesn't works good for me:

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById('prototypeMap');

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = imgElement.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = imgElement.offsetHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(imgElement,0,0); //ERROR
```

The last line give me this error:
TypeError: Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883064/securityerror-load-an-image-in-canvas-modify-it-and-create-dataurl

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you seem to have done no research on your own before asking.

Comment: I have done research, I am still making it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using SVG image tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag

And then use the other SVG elements to draw on top.